# Same data takes more space on external hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, filesystems, formatting

My internal 1TB SSD disk on the laptop has folders which are consuming 1.45GB of space. This SSD is NTFS formatted.
I recently bought Seagate 5TB and formatted it exFat so that it can work on both windows and mac. Now mac still is not able to show the disk in Finder.

The problem I am facing is that when I cut 1.45GB of data from SSD and paste it in my external HDD, it reduces the available space on the external HDD by 10.2GB which doesn't make any sense to me.

This happens with any data that I try to paste into this new disk.

I am worried if I got a fraud disk from Amazon.

Any troubleshoot ideas will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

exFat cluster size on a HDD of 5TB is 32KB

NTFS cluster size on an HDD of 1TB is 4KB

If your folder contains a TON of very small files this is a problem that you could be having.  Since the minimum storage space a file will take on your new drive will be 32KB regardless of the size and only 4KB on your previous drive

Comment: so the solution is to reformat the 5TB HDD with exFat and change the cluster size to 4KB when formatting. Will that solve this issue?

Comment: If there are lots of large files then this is the case.  Reformatting would be a good test and and quick process to determine if this is causing your issue.

Comment: Wonder how one has down voted. This is a real issue!